# How can I Fix the ValueError in Substitution

Tags: python

I'm using a simple line to substitute a part of a string in an array for the corresponding three letter sequence another array.

They represent airports/hubs.

```
for i in range(nV):
    for j in range(nV):
        for z in range(nV):
            cidades = [cities[int(z)] for z in optimalpath[i][j].split(">")]
        optimalpath[i][j] = ">".join(cidades)
```

It's giving me an error in the line that starts with `cidades`, saying the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marcelo.novaes\code\projects\floydwarshall\floydwarshall_malha.py", line 146, in <module>
    cidades = [cities[int(z)] for z in optimalpath[i][j].split(">")]
  File "c:\Users\marcelo.novaes\code\projects\floydwarshall\floydwarshall_malha.py", line 146, in <listcomp>
    cidades = [cities[int(z)] for z in optimalpath[i][j].split(">")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

There is no `''` in the range so I can't seem to find why it's using `''` as a value for 'z'.

Comment: Sorry if it's a hasty answer but i have to shut down very soon. Have a look if the issue is conencted with you re-declaring the variable z. The 3rd level loop uses z and then you re-declare it in the list-comprehension inside that loop

Comment: We need a [mre]. There is no way for us to help with the information provided. `z` gets every element of `optimalpath[i][j].split(">")` which we have no idea what it is

Comment: For example, `">asg>".split(">")` will produce `['', 'asg', '']`

Comment: Thanks folks. It was indeed creating a blank value. I then substituted the blanks for nothing and it worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split sometimes givess you empty list elements. Example:

```py
s = "bcb"
l = s.split("b")
print(l)
```

Output:

```
["", "c", ""]
```

You should check if the string is not empty (`bool("")` is always False). Example:

```py
s = ""
if s:
    print("s is not empty")
else:
    print("s is empty")
```

When s is `""`, this prints `s is empty`, and when it's for example `"example"`, it prints `s is not empty`.

Comment: Thank you! This was it. Sorry for the delay in responding. Cheers!

Comment: @mcnovaes no problem !